# Gallery image display

Tags: android

I am very new to android platform. I am calling this method `ga.setSelection(1);` in my `onCreate()`  method. After running my application first image is focused but I want focused image and also display the same time. Can anybody please tell me how to display the image in gallery view?

Thanks
 Raj

Comment: Refer this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example)

Comment: Can you give a little more info about the setup. Is the class too large to post snippits of? I interpret several things as a gallery view. Are you talking about something like http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?d816500473.png ? Maybe post some samples of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: hi Du3 exactly like that can you give example for that. now what happen is after running the application the galley view is display and first image is focused and after click any image that image display the screen but want focused image with display the corresponding image both are same time. can you anyone help me for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
gal.setSelection(1, true);
```